# :app:processDebugResources FAILED gradle

Tags: android, gradle

everything was working fine i dont know what happend
no its not an XML file..not its not clean rebuild ..no its not sync ...sos what could it be...

this is my gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }


}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}

this is the error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\User-Pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741818

please someone help

Answer (score 0):

Your virus scanner (Avast for me) probably detected this threat as a false positive for malware. This happened and it alerted me. You must take it out of quarantine or allow it. If you can't, I recommend re-downloading build-tools version.

From: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

"Open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar. If you're not using Android Studio, you can download tools using the sdkmanager command-line tool.

When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash  appears in the check box next to the package.

To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark."